# The best way to pass function as props in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components A and B. Component A has a restriction on button function based on conditions, I want Component B's  button to make use of the restriction function in Component A

```
//Component A

state = {
  disabled = true,
  password='Admin'
}

authorize = (e) => {
  var passcode = 1234
  if (passcode == this.state.password) {
    this.setState({ disabled: false })
  } else {
    alert("Access code is incorrect please enter the correct access code")
  }

}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          style={{ width: 200 }}
          placeholder="Enter Admin Access code "
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
        />
        <Button bsStyle='primary' onClick={(e) => this.authorize(e)}> Enter</Button>
      </form>
      // Button disabled waiting for authorize function to be called
      <Button disabled={this.state.disabled} >I am disabled</Button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Component B

```
render() {
  return (
    // want to be able to do something like
    <Button disabled={this.props.disabled}>I am disabled too</Button>
  );
}
```

I want to make use of the authorize function in Component B, don't really know how to

Comment: Where is the child component tag in parent component ?

Comment: Can you check details here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: The general answer is to "lift up state", as in, move the `disabled` state to the parent component, pass it down as prop, and also pass a function to change the state to component A.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html